In a .NET 8 console app what is a good approach to configure an HTTP Client or message handlers with parameters determined for each request?
TLDR; What is the best approach to build HttpClients where a per-request value needs to be passed to the HttpClientFactory to construct the correct requests?
Some background:
We have a background service application (console app basically) that receives messages from a message bus. These messages contains a TenantId and a ConfigurationId.
Based on those two options, we need to find a set of configurations for an API. Specifically we need to find the right database (tenantId) and find the right configuration record (configurationId), which in turns gives us 2 things:

An URL
An API Key

Then we need to call the API and do some stuff with that.
I am strugling with the best approach for doing something like this in .NET 8.
Currently I have the following type of setup, but it seems "wrong" somehow, that I need to wrap my ApiClient as a factory class in this manner.
Factory Class
public class ApiClientFactory {
    public ApiClientFactory(IServiceProvider provider, HttpClient client)
    {
        this.provider = provider;
        this.client = client;
    }
    
    public IApiClient Create(Configuration config)
    {
        client.BaseAddress = config.Url;
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer ${config.ApiKey}");
        return ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<ApiClient>(this.provider, client);
    }
}

And the DI setup looks something like:
services.AddScoped<IApiClient, ApiClient>(); 
services.AddHttpClient<ApiClientFactory>();

// Not really what happen but for simplicity:
services.AddScoped<MessageBusHandler>();


Then in our message handler class we do something like the following:
public class MessageBusHandler
{
    public MessageBusHandler(ApiClientFactory factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public void HandleMessage(CallApiMessage message)
    {
        // Find tenant/config from DB omitted...
        var config = GetConfiguration(message.TenantId, message.ConfigurationId);
        this.factory.Create(config).CallRemoteApi(message.SomeParameters);
    }
}

All of this works...I just keep thinking that it would be better to refactor this into a message handler, so that I could somehow discard the ApiClientFactory since registering it as an HttpClient just seems wrong.
So are there other good options for creating multiple HttpClients for the same API but with different configurations (discovered runtime)?
UPDATE: Added a few details to the DI setup. The MessageBusHandler is a BIT more complicated in that its resolved in its own messaging pipeline, but its not important for the question i think.

Can you add the relevant DI configuration code to your question?

Everything you're doing in your Create method inside ApiClientFactory, you can do in the DI setup: services.AddHttpClient(o => { });

Injecting an HttpClient into ApiClientFactory seems tricky to me, because a single ApiClientFactory instance will always return the same HttpClient instance from its ApiClientFactory.Create method.

@GHDevOps - how would you go about accepting the Configuration config as input in the AddHttpClient call? I might be dense, but the config is essentially retrieved from the database, based on input in the message that is being handled.

@Steven the point of injecting the HttpClient and using AddHttpClient is to let the DefaultHttpClientFactory handle the lifetime of the HttpClient and its handlers, thus I should get a new one each time the ApiClientFactory is resolved (note its not registered as a singleton).

@EsbenBach why are you storing an API key in a database? If you're using NET8 in Blazor, it's easily persisted from backend to client. In fact, it's easily persisted in .Net Framework as well. There's never a need to store it.

@GHDevOps not using Blazor, its essentially a console app (actually its hosted in Service Fabric, but not relevant here). I am storing it in a database, because it needs to be stored somewhere, and it changes from tenant to tenant. That detail is irrelevant for this question though. I might as well have stored it in azure key vault or some other place.
The question would be equally valid if I were to send a unique identifier to the API based on which tenant was selected in the message input. The point is the value comes from a configuration the tenant has defined "runtime" if you want.

IHttpClientFactory has a very nice "NAMED-Client" setup.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-8.0#named-clients   and "TYPED-Client" setup https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-8.0#typed-clients

If your "business logic code" always hits the same http-server....then you can inject a TYPED client into that business logic.    if your "business logic code" .. needs to make a run-time decision between different http-servers..then use the magic-string named-clients.      I like to put my names of my named-clients in a single-source-of-truth-dictionary.. so you can "track down" where the magic-string for the named-client is referenced.

But basically, the IHttpClientFactory is  (drum roll). the "Factory Design Pattern", but already nicely coded up for you ( and me).    with a few options for the "key" for the factory.   a magic-string-NAME or using a class-TYPE.

@EsbenBach the class you name ApiClientFactory isn't a factory at all, it's a typed HttpClient. The real factory is the HttpClientFactory with which you registered your typed client when you called AddHttpClient. You can have multiple typed or named clients, with different configuration for each. You can also specify your own headers in an HttpRequestMessage instead of using the defautl headers

What are you trying to do? Are you using a specific message bus library? It seems the problems are used by incorrectly implementing and using patterns like factories and message busses, in a multi-tenant environment. For a small number of tenants it may be enough to register one named client per tenant. For a larger number it may be better to set the correct headers in each request message. The message bus library may already have ways to handle multitenancy

@PanagiotisKanavos I am trying to have the same client implementation, but with different properties on the outgoing request (BaseUrl/ApiKey in this case), based on which tenant its currently executing for, without preregistrering clients during startup, as the configuration may change runtime.
Specifically i am using Azure Service Bus, but regardless of that SDK the issue is that all suggestions relates to the information being available in the DI pipeline.
Had this been asp.net core it would correspond to having the parameters in the BODY of the http request availble during DI.

@EsbenBach Azure Service Bus works fine with ASP.NET Core code and DI

I will try to answer my own question here, even though its not a "solution" as such.
Basically what the question ask is: How to use the HttpClientFactory for typed clients with request context parameters used for construction.
It seems like that is not possible, because it is not possible to supply parameters during construction, if those parameters are not part of the DI scope.
It seems like there are two workarounds (maybe more, but these are the two I have found):

Create a typed client, which is actually a factory for the underlying client. The approach I took in the ApiClient factory in the question.
Depend on the HttpClientFactory instead, and have a factory class (similar to the APiClientFactory) create new instances of the typed client, while using HttpClientFactory explicitly.

Variant 2 has the added benefit that it is possible to create "App DI Scope" aware delegating handlers (by default delegating handlers use a different scope than the App scope). Described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-factory#message-handler-scopes-in-ihttpclientfactory
Basically I ended up with variant 2.....
UPDATE
Turns out Kiota have the same "problem" as me, and they solved in a manner similar to what I have in my question. I.e. a "factory" class that is actually a typed client.
For anyone interested in that approach:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openapi/kiota/tutorials/dotnet-dependency-injection#create-a-client-factory

Or change your code to use DI properly. Azure Service Bus doesn't prevent you from using .NET Core's middleware, quite the opposite. Have you tried adding Microsoft.Extensions.Azure to your project?

@PanagiotisKanavos - how would that help anything? Service Bus is part of the DI flow. What I do not have is a "request pipeline" for messages similar to how HttpContext/HttpRequests are build in Asp.Net core.
Likewise, even IF I had the message part of the scope, I would still need to know how to extract the relevant information from the message. Granted I could write some middleware for that. But the building blocks are missing.
